# Select username and role name

Tags: jpa, hql

As the title indicates I'm trying to select both username and role name by using the following query.

```
select u.username, r.name
from users u, role r
inner join users_roles ur
  on ur.user_id = u.id
where username = ?;
```

However I'm getting the below error

```
[2017-04-05 21:34:49] [42P01] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "u"
[2017-04-05 21:34:49] Hint: There is an entry for table "u", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
[2017-04-05 21:34:49] Position: 79
```

My user entity is as follows

```
@Entity(name = "users") // Postgres doesn't like the table name "user"
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
...
```

And my role entity is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;
...
```

Any clues about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.username, role.name
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_roles
  ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN role
  ON users_roles.role_id = role.id
WHERE username = ?
```

Comment: Please add some context to this answer. What does this query do? How does this solve the original question?

Comment: The query will return a list of tuples where first column is username and the second is the name of the role. I'm using this in conjunction with spring security.